# Is there some workaround to create “deny” rules for Google Cloud Firewall

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Docs about Google Cloud [Networks and Firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking) clearly says:

> Firewall rules are only "allow" rules. You cannot create "deny" rules.

But we still need those deny-rules, and I believe this is an essential option. Amazon’s VPC can do this.

So, are there some workarounds to create “deny” rules?

Answer (score 1):

Until GCE supports outbound firewall rules, you'll have to use an alternative such as [iptables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo).

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Platform currently allows creating deny rules. It is easily visible on the Console UI when creating a rule on 'Action on match' (Allow or Deny), and you'll find several examples in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#configuration_examples).